# Error "parserOptions.project" Has Been Set for @typescript-eslint/parser. in Webpack File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, eslint

Halo...

In my React.js app, I got this error in my `webpack.config.js` from eslint

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: webpack.config.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.
```

That error message is pointing the first line of my `webpack.config.js` file. Here is my webpack file.

```js
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: `${__dirname}/public/index.html`,
  filename: "index.html",
  inject: "body",
});

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "transformed.js",
    path: `${__dirname}/build`,
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve("src"),
      "@routes": path.resolve("src/client/routes"),
      "@lib": path.resolve("src/client/lib"),
      "@designTokens": path.resolve("src/client/lib/designTokens"),
      "@constants": path.resolve("src/client/lib/constants"),
      "@assets": path.resolve("src/client/assets"),
      "@context": path.resolve("src/client/context"),
      "@components": path.resolve("src/client/components"),
    },
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    host: "dev.thinkfast.app",
    port: 8080,
    https: {
      key: "../_cert/thinkfast.react.key.pem", // <<< cert key file
      cert: "../_cert/thinkfast.react.cert.pem", // <<< cert file
    },
  },
};
```

And this is my `.eslintrc.json` file.

```js
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"], // Your TypeScript files extension

      // As mentioned in the comments, you should extend TypeScript plugins here,
      // instead of extending them outside the `overrides`.
      // If you don't want to extend any rules, you don't need an `extends` attribute.
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
      ],

      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["./tsconfig.json"] // Specify it only for TypeScript files
      }
    }
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/mouse-events-have-key-events": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": ["off"],
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["off"],
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
    "no-case-declarations": "off",
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "no-plusplus": "off",
    "prefer-rest-params": ["off"],
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", {}, {}],
    "react/no-danger": ["off"]
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "webpack": {
        "config": "./webpack.config.js"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my `tsconfig.json` file.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["./webpack.config.js"]
}
```

And this is my `package.json` file.

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "homepage": "https://thinkfast.app:8080",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/css": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint --color .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --color .",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.28.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.28.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0 || ^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

I'm really stuck with that error because that is blocking the Husky precommit hook. I know I can bypass it, but I'm afraid that'll cause more problems.
Been looking other "parserOptions.project" issues on google, still can't find the matching solution.

Thank you very much!